# Canary stage in Spinnaker with cloud provider as K8

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I have installed dev-spinnaker from [git repo readme](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker). I'm able to create a server group and verified that the POD is launched in my K8s cluster. But I'm not able to select `Account` in `Canary` stage.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Before the Canary stage, I have configured a docker tigger. I tried `Canary` stage after the `Find Image From Cluster` stage also, got same result.

As it says in second screenshot, "You must have a Bake or Find AMI before a Canary stage", but there is no bake or find AMI in docker context. So, how to enable Canary in docker context?

Comment: Which canary judge are you attempting to use? If it's the [OpsMx](http://www.opsmx.com/) judge I will forward this question to them to see what the status of their kubernetes support is. If you're using the OSS judge, you will have to wait until it is fully released/supported for K8s in Q3: https://www.spinnaker.io/community/releases/roadmap/.

Comment: Yes, I'm part of OpsMx team. I was looking this issue, seems like the UI is not showing the "K8" account in Canary stage page. Will update

Comment: @lwander Created issue, please check--> https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/1814